# Обязательное указание размерности при передаче двумерного массива

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

Допустим, у нас есть двумерный массив. Почему при передаче его в функцию, например `void f(int x[][n], int, int)`, мы обязательно должны писать `n`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Про то, что компилятор должен знать количество элементов в строке матрицы для доступа к `x[i][j]`, Вам уже написали.

Хочу отметить, что в gcc (*но не в g++*) можно писать функции так:

```
 int f(int lines, int cols, int х[][cols]) { ...
```

передавая размерность (и таким образом  сообщая данные о размерности компилятору) в списке аргументов.

Соответственно, такая функция может обрабатывать матрицы *разного* размера.

---

Вероятно Вы уже знаете, как обрабатывать матрицы произвольного размера (обращаться к i,j-му элементу) на C++ или C (если компилятор не поддерживает передачу размерности в аргументах функции (как позволяет делать gcc)). Но, на всякий случай (а может кому-нибудь еще пригодится), вот пример:

```
void f (int *matr, int nlines, int ncols) {
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < nlines; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
      printf("%d%c", matr[i * ncols + j], j == ncols - 1 ? '\n' : ' ');
  puts("");
}
```

(я предполагаю, что Вы уже слышали об эквивалентности (с рядом оговорок) массивов и указателей в C и C++)

Т.е. мы рассматриваем двумерный массив из nlines строк размером ncols элементов как одномерный (ведь в памяти элементы матрицы располагаются друг за другом, по строкам, без каких-либо разрывов между ними).

Вызывать же f() нужно так:

```
  ....
  int a[3][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 4},
         {11, 12, 13, 14},
         {21, 22, 23, 24}};

  f(&a[0][0], 3, 4);
  ....
```

Comment: Вопреки распространненому заблуждению, никакой "эквивалентности массивов и указателей в C и C++" не существует. Наоброт, ситуации, когда такая "эквивалентность" может наблюдаться являются *оговорками*.

Comment: @AnT, да, если смотреть на язык строго, то эквивалентности нет. А если через призму синтаксиса операций, как их обычно видит программист (да и машинных команд, которые генерит компилятор для доступа к элементам), то аналогии очевидны (впрочем, это наверное субъективно)

Comment: Отнюдь. Семантика применения `[i][j]` к двойному указателю и к языковому 2D массиву отличается *фундаментально*. И именно это будет сразу же видно в тех же машинных командах (!). Встроенный оператор `[]` является *перегруженным* и в С и в С++ и делает соврешенно *разные* вещи в случаях, когда операнд является указателем или массивом. Опытному взгляду это заметно даже на 1D массиве. Но на 2D массиве разница сразу бросается в глаза.

Comment: @AnT, с этим не поспоришь (тут язык сбивал с ног многих начинающих -))

Comment: @AnT *как правило* массив в выражении превращается в указатель на первый элемент в С,  а *исключения* можно по пальцам посчитать (к примеру, `sizeof(a)`, `&a + 1` vs. `&a[0] + 1`, `char a[] = "hi";`).

Comment: @jfs: Во-первых, явление "array-type decay" никоим образом не создает *эквивалентности* между массивами и указателями даже в тех контекстах, где оно имеет место. Человеку, знакомому с семантикой массива и природой этого явления понятно, что никакой эквивалентности тут нет. Во-вторых, речь идет о С++, где таких контекстов заметно больше. В-третьих, считать индивидуальные контексты на пальцах - занятие бессмысленное. Общее правило таково: в *объектном* контексте (object context) массив ведет себя как массив, в контексте значений (value context) массив ведет себя как указатель. Считай, 50/50 :)

Answer (score 4):

Формально - потому что так предписывается стандартом.

Причина этого заключается в том, что двумерный массив размера `m x n` располагается в памяти так:

```
(0, 0), (0, 1), ..., (0, n-1), (1, 0), (1, 1), ..., (1, n-1), ...
```

Соответственно `x[i][j]` это то же самое что `((int*)x)[i*n + j]`, и чтобы это вычислить нужно знать `n`, a `m` (т.е первую размерность) знать не обязательно.

В общем случае, это распространяется на массивы любой размерности: необходимо передавать все размерности, кроме первой, по аналогичной причине.

Answer (score 3):

Это чисто искусственный директивный запрет, присутствующий в стандарте языка, и никакой однозначной "материальной" причины для такого запрета не существует.

Согласно [DR#393](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#393) этот запрет из языка *устраняют* к C++17. Мне еще не совсем ясно будут ли разрешена только форма `int (*x)[]`, или также и форма `int x[][]` (скорее всего обе). Но общий запрет уходит в небытие. Пользы от его устранения в общем-то немного, но тем не менее.

Соответствующая часть стандарта еще присутствует в С++14

> **8.3.5 Functions**
>
> **8** If the type of a parameter includes a type of the form “pointer to array of unknown bound of T” or “reference to array of unknown bound of T,” the program is ill-formed.

но ее уже нет в первых черновиках после С++14. (Компиляторы пока продолжают отвергать такие параметры, хотя clang++ спокойно проглатывает параметры типа `int (*x)[]` независимо от настроек спецификации языка - "дырка" в clang)

Что касается причин и контекста существования такого запрета - см. ниже.

---

Для начала заметим, что сами по себе тип "массив неизвестного размера" `T []` поддерживается и в С, и в С++. И там, и там он является *неполным* типом, ничем принципиально не отличающимся от других неполных типов. Тип "указатель на массив неизвестного размера" `T (*)[]` также полностью легален и в С, и в С++, и трактуется как обычный указатель на неполный тип, со всеми характерными для них ограничениями.

1. Обратите внимание, что язык С++ разрешает и всегда разрешал использовать объявления параметров типа "массив из элементов неполного типа" в качестве параметров функций

   ```
   typedef struct X X;

   void foo(X x[]); // OK в С++, ошибка в С
   ```

   Также оба языка разрешают использовать указатели на неполные типы в качестве параметров

   ```
   void foo(X *x); // Указатель на неполный тип, ОК и в С, и в С++
   ```

   Поэтому популярные аргументы из разряда "компилятор не будет знать, как выполнять адресную арифметику" тут попадают совершенно "мимо кассы". Это никогда не было преградой для создания указателей на неполные типы ни в С, ни в С++. Правила этих языков просто запрещают применять адресную арифметику к указателям на неполные типы - вот и все.
2. Обратите также внимание, что при при объявлении параметра функции типа "массив", и в С, и в С++ тип массив `T []` почти сразу автоматически трансформируются в тип указатель `T *`. То есть мой пример выше c параметром, объявленным как `X x[]` будет в конечном итоге рассматриваться как

   ```
   void foo(X *x); // Указатель на неполный тип, ОК и в С, и в С++
   ```

   Что характерно в таком виде это объявление параметра является легальным и в языке С тоже (как уже показано выше). То есть запрет на объявление параметра как `X x[]` в языке С является чисто синтаксическим, поверхностным - это просто исторический "каприз" синтаксиса языка С.
3. Переходя к вашему случаю: согласно формальным правилам автоматических трансформаций типов параметров, параметр, объявленный как `int x[][]` (если бы он был разрешен) должен был бы автоматически трансформироваться к параметру типа `int (*)[]`, т.е. это просто указатель на неполный тип - на массив неизвестного размера. Сам по себе, такой тип является полностью легальным как в С, так и в С++. Ничего особенного в нем нет

   ```
   int (*p)[] = 0; // ОК и в С, и в С++
   ```

   То есть никаких проблем с точки зрения типа указателя, как такового тут нет.

   При этом язык С разрешает

   ```
   void foo(int (*x)[]); // ОК в С
   ```

   Что же касается С++, несмотря на то, что язык С++ не запрещает параметров типа "массив элементов неполного типа" и поддерживает тип "указатель на массив неизвестного размера", он в то же время отвергает оба варианта

   ```
   void foo(int x[][]); // Ошибка в С++
   void bar(int (*x)[]); // Ошибка в С++
   ```

В чем же тут дело?

Ответ на это вопрос давал в свое время Dan Saks и относится он в тому периоду, когда язык С++ еще только готовился к стандартизации

http://www.drdobbs.com/stepping-up-to-c/184403070

> Комитет решил, что функции такого вида, т.е. принимающие указатели или ссылку на массив неизвестного размера, усложняют правила сопоставления объявлений и определений (declaration matching) и правила разрешения перегрузки (overload resolution) в языке С++. Комитет согласился, что так как польза от таких функций невелика и они довольно редки, проще всего будет просто запретить их.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>



template < typename T , size_t FirstDim , size_t SecondDim >
void out_array( T (&arr)[FirstDim][SecondDim] )
{
    for ( auto & f : arr )
    {
        for ( auto & s : f )
        {
            std::cout << s << ' ' ;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl ;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int arr [4][2] = 
        { 
            { 3 , 4 } ,
            { 8 , 2 } ,
            { 1 , 0 } ,
            { 5 , 9 } ,
        } ;
    out_array ( arr ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> мы обязательно должны писать n ???????

Да, иначе компилятор не сможет определить положение ячеек в строках кроме нулевой.

И вообще, ты же как-то объявил такой массив с константной размерностью - надо её и указать.

Если массив динамический и рваный, то надо передавать `int **x`.

Если массив динамический, но не рваный, то ты сам отвечаешь за приведение индекса и передаёшь одномерный массив.

Answer (score -1):

Можно принимать в функции указатель, а размер массива хранить в переменной вот так:

```
const int SIZE = 5; 
void print (int* m) {
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        for(int j =0; j<SIZE; j++){
            printf(" %d", m + SIZE*i + j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 
}

.....
print ((int*) b);
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял)